# Is there any inbuild module to convert unicode chars to utf8 in python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Here my issue is I've some input files, which are in utf-16 and "UTF-8 Unicode C program text, with CRLF line terminators". Those files has variables which should be replaced using "pyratemp" template processing. So, when there is file with "UTF-8 Unicode C program text, with CRLF line terminators" file type which has some chinese characters in file are failing with 
`"UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u503c' in position 196: ordinal not in range(128)"`

Comment: You don't need a module to convert strings to utf8, you just do `"some text".encode('utf8')`. That said, it looks like you're trying to _read_ text from a file, which is completely unrelated to encoding text (it's the exact opposite). What is your actual question?

Comment: Actual I've file - Not a string. The file contains some unicode characters and the format is 'UTF-8 Unicode C program text, with CRLF line terminators'. Also it has some variables to replace at run-time. So, I'm using pyratemp module to replace the variables.temp_sql = pyratemp.Template(filename=sourceFile, data=data_hash, encoding='UTF-8')"